# Multiple modes for line-oriented command interpreters with Python Cmd class

Tags: python, shell, cmd, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a CLI (line-oriented command interpreters) using Python Cmd class with support for 2 or more modes, with each mode have different set of commands, with commands to switch between them.

Currently I implemented 2 modes using 2 separate classes for each mode, then I set the next class to execute in a state variable:

```
class OpMode(Cmd):
    def do_show(self, line):
        :
    def do_configure(self, line): # switch to ConfigMode
        ctx.state = 'config'
        return True

class ConfigMode(Cmd):
    def do_set(self, line):
        : 
    def do_exit(self, line):  # go back to OpMode
        ctx.state = 'op'
        return True

# in main ...
while 1:
    if ctx.state == 'op':
        opcli.cmdloop()
    elif ctx.state == 'conf':
        confcli.cmdloop()
    else:
        break
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with a single Cmd class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single cmd instance will not improve your code. You could keep track of your state inside the Cmd class and then for each command action adjust your respone accordingly.

However, what you probably want is a clearer transition between different states. You can do this as follows:

```
def do_configure(self, line):
    config = ConfigMode(...)
    config.cmdloop()
```